# Nhibernate multiple unique-key on same field

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a hierarchical structure like this:

```
class Node
{
  Node Parent;
  string Name;
  string Code;
}
```

and I need to reflect in nhibernate mapping files that the combinations (Parent, Name) and (Parent, Code) BOTH are unique (even when Parent is null). Does nhibernate allows multiple unique-key on the same field? Something in the likes of

```
<many-to-one name="Parent" class="Node" column="ParentId" unique-key="CK1" unique-key="CK2" />
```

or some other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<database-object>` to create all the indexes you want.